# Mi función asincrona no retorna nada

Tags: javascript, nodejs

estoy intentando crear un iterador asincrono en nodejs, y dentro del iterador quiero sacar los "stats" de los ficheros en la ruta que recibe por parametro, la función que tengo tiene el valor correcto dentro del scope, pero al salir, el valor no se guarda en la variable "value_return", y por ende retorna undefined, alguien sabe que puede ser?

```
fileStatsAsync()
    {
        let     current = 0;
        const   last = (this.path_data.length - 1);
        const   data = this.path_data;
        const   path = this.path;

        return {
            async next()
            {
                while (current <= last)
                {
                    let value_return;
                    let is_dir;
                    let absolute_files = ft_path.join(ft_path.normalize(path), data[current]);
                    
                    async function ft_get_stat_file()
                    {
                        return is_dir = await fs.stat(absolute_files, (err, stats) =>
                        {
                            if (err){
                                throw (err);
                            }
                            else{
                                return(stats); // Necesito este valor
                            }
                        });
                    };

                    value_return = await ft_get_stat_file(); // Undefined
                    return { done: false, value: value_return, iter: current++ }
                }
                if (current > last) {
                    return { done: true }
                }
            },
            [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
                return this
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Podrías utilizar [`fsPromises.stat()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesstatpath-options) (disponible en NodeJS 10.x en adelante) que efectivamente devuelve una Promesa que podrás usar con `await`. Saludos

Comment: Es verdad Mauricio, muchas gracias!, con eso si lo puedo solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema puede ser en el `return is_dir = await fs.stat`, ya que no espera el valor y te regresa el evento en tu variable.

Lo que yo haría de hecho es quitar la función asíncrona y hacer la consulta directo al fs.stat.

```
while (current <= last)
    {
        let value_return;
        let is_dir;
        let absolute_files = ft_path.join(ft_path.normalize(path), data[current]);
       //como ya tienes un async, el fs.stat te debe regresar el valor a tu variable directo.
         
        value_return = await fs.stat(absolute_files);

        return { done: false, value: value_return, iter: current++ }
    }
```

Comment: Eso funcionaría si fs.stat fuera fs.statAsync, pero como no es sincrona, da error porque devuelve 2 callbacks (err, data), estoy intentando resolverlo sin (fs.statsync) alguna otra sugerencia :( ?

Comment: `(node:5008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined`

Comment: Tu respuesta tiene un error. `fs.stat` no devuelve una Promesa y tampoco un objeto *thenable*, por lo cual el uso de `await` no es correcto. Saludos